# Prove that this subset is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$. For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $x_i\in H$ and $r_i\in\mathbb{R}$ be given. Assume that $S=\{x\in H: (x,x_i)\geq r_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n\}$ is not empty.

I need to prove that $S$ has a unique element of minimum norm. I already proved that the set is convex, and now I want to show that it is closed. But this is where I don't know how to proceed.

I wanted to say, let $\{s_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $S$, converging to a limit $s\in H$. I want to show that this limit is in $S$. Is this the correct approach? And if it is, can somebody give me a hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product is continuous: from $s_k \to s$ it follows that

$(s_k,y) \to (s,y)$ for all $y \in H$.

Hence

$(s_k,x_i) \to (s,x_i)$ for  $i=1,...,n.$

Since $(s_k,x_i) \ge r_i$, we get $(s,x_i) \ge r_i$, thus $s \in H$.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I should use the continuity of the inner product, but I wasn't sure I could state it like this.